# Not echoing the data from the table?

Tags: php

In my code, it should be echoing "Testing Post", as that is entry with the ID of 1 (I am on the page `blog.php?ID=1`)

Here is my code, it is not echoing anything; merely empty divs. (Note that the connection is working fine and no errors are shown)

```
$ID = (int) $_GET["ID"];    
$getPost = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Blogs WHERE ID='$ID'");
$gP = mysql_fetch_object($getPost);
echo"
<h1 id='PostTitle'>", $gP->Title,"</h1><br />
<p id='PostContent'></p>";
```

Comment: `$ID = (int) $_GET["ID"];` <-- much simpler, cleaner, and more effective

Comment: What do you see when you `var_dump( $gP );`?

Comment: var_dump returns bool(false)

Comment: That means the query didn't find a matching row.

Comment: If you echo the query, and then run it by hand, does it find anything?

Comment: Try using `mysql_error` to check for SQL errors. If you see none, and you are assured your database connection is working, that means your query is not returning any rows.

Comment: If you are sure that a record with `$ID` exists in you DB, check mySQL error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run some checks to avoid sql injections and `Undefined index` warnings.

```
if (isset($_GET['ID']) && is_int($_GET['ID']))
{
    $id = $_GET['ID']; 

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Blogs WHERE `ID`={$id}");
    if (false !== ($result = mysql_fetch_object($query)))
    {
        echo '<h1 id="PostTitle">' . $result->Title . '</h1><br />'.
             '<p id="PostContent"></p>';
    }
}
```

Anyway, you should try to avoid using mysql_* methods as it's deprecated in PHP >= 5.5.